# AutoMapper - Mapping View Model Collections?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

So I have a View Model like this:

```
Public Class CategoryViewModel
    Public Property ID As Integer
    Public Property Name As String
    Public Property Display As Boolean
    Public Property DisplayIndex As Integer

End Class
```

And then this:

```
Public Class CategoriesViewModel
    Public Property Categories As IEnumerable(Of CategoryViewModel)
End Class
```

How do I map a collection of categories (Domain.Category) to the Categories (CategoryViewModel) property in the CategoriesViewModel?

Also, how would you handle a collection of Sub Categories? Would you make another View Model for that and have a collection of those on the CategoryViewModel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tell automapper how the types should map, so tell AM how Category maps to CategoryViewModel.  AM doesn't care if you map an array of categories to a list of categoriesviewmodel as long as you tell it how to map the types.

For the second part are sub categories self referencing?

Comment: @Derek - Self Referencing? Sorry, I am new to this, so what does that mean?

Comment: Does you Category class have a collection of Category.

Comment: @Derek - No, I have Categories that have Sub Categories.

Comment: So, no I wouldn't make another viewmodel for that.  One suggestion name your view models based on what they do like CategoryDisplay or CategoryInput.  So in your case my CategoryDisplay view model would have a collection of Category and Category would have a collection os SubCategory.  In some cases your database model entities might be 1 to 1 mappings to your view model but that's ok.  Check out ASP.NET MVC in Action 2, it's an excellent resource.

Comment: @Derek - So if you do not have a Model for each entity, then what do you use? The POCO classes? I was under the impression you did not want to use domain objects in your view/model, but rather a View Model per entity. - Thanks!

Comment: You're correct, you don't want to use domain objects in your vm.  I should have been more clear on the naming.  In your example above you really don't need the CategoriesViewModel class as the view can be typed as List<CategoryViewModel>.  If your screen had other things on it you could create a class called XYZDisplay and it might contain  list of CategoryViewModel and a list of ProductViewModel and other things.

Comment: Creating a view model is a matter of looking at what you want displayed on the screen and making a model to represent it.  The goal being making the data easy to display in your view so you don't have a bunch of logic in the view that has to dig around a model to find what it needs.